# Index Match Cell Contains Text

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but I'm getting an N/A error.

I have a cell that contains comma separated addresses. If one of the addresses matches an address in another table, I need a value from another cell in the prior table.

```
INDEX( GoogleFormResults[B], MATCH("*"&[@Address]&"*", GoogleFormResults[A],0))
```

Example Address in the Table:

```
707 W Cesar Chavez Ave LOS ANGELES CA 90067
```

Example GoogleFormResults[A]

```
4101 Crenshaw Blvd LOS ANGELES CA 90008, 707 W Cesar Chavez Ave LOS ANGELES CA 90067, 6820 Eastern Ave BELL GARDENS CA 90201, 12270 Paramount Blvd DOWNEY CA 90242, 1399 Artesia Blvd. GARDENA CA 90247, 14441 Inglewood Ave HAWTHORNE CA 90250, 4651 Firestone Blvd SOUTH GATE CA 90280, 5871 Firestone Blvd SOUTH GATE CA 90280, 19503 Normandie Ave TORRANCE CA 90501, 19340 Hawthorne Blvd TORRANCE CA 90503, 22015 Hawthorne Blvd TORRANCE CA 90503, 2601 Skypark Dr TORRANCE CA 90505, 8450 La Palma Ave BUENA PARK CA 90620, 5420 Lapalma Ave LA PALMA CA 90623, 1000 E Imperial Hwy LA HABRA CA 90631, 1340 SOUTH BEACH BLVD LA HABRA CA 90631, 1390 S. Beach Blvd. LA HABRA CA 90631, 14865 Telegraph Rd LA MIRADA CA 90638, 11729 Imperial Hwy NORWALK CA 90650, 8500 Washington Blvd PICO RIVERA CA 90660, 13310 TELEGRAPH ROAD SANTA FE SPRINGS CA 90670, 12540 Beach Blvd. STANTON CA 90680, 12840 Beach Blvd STANTON CA 90680, 12701 TOWNE CENTER D CERRITOS CA 90703, 2770 CARSON STREET LAKEWOOD CA 90712, 12120 Carson Street HAWAIIAN GARDENS CA 90716, 14501 LAKEWOOD BLVD PARAMOUNT CA 90723, 20226 AVALON BLVD. CARSON CA 90746, 151 EAST 5TH STREET LONG BEACH CA 90802, 3705 E. South Street LONG BEACH CA 90805, 7250 Carson Blvd LONG BEACH CA 90808, 7480 Carson Blvd LONG BEACH CA 90808, 6750 Kimball Ave Chino CA 91708, 3943 Grand Ave CHINO CA 91710, 3951 Grand Ave CHINO CA 91710, 1275 N Azusa Ave COVINA CA 91722, 4901 Santa Anita Ave EL MONTE CA 91731, 1425 N Hacienda Blvd LA PUENTE CA 91744, 17150 Gale Ave CITY OF INDUSTRY CA 91745, 17835 E. Gale Ave. HACIENDA HEIGHTS CA 91745, 4155 Wineville Ave MIRA LOMA CA 91752, 4250 Hamner Ave MIRA LOMA CA 91752, 1333 N Mountain Ave ONTARIO CA 91762, 951 N. Milliken Ave. ONTARIO CA 91764, 1180 S Diamond Bar Blvd Diamond Bar CA 91765, 80 RIO RANCHO ROAD POMONA CA 91766, 780 E Arrow Hwy Pomona CA 91767, 1827 WALNUT GROVE BLVD ROSEMEAD CA 91770, 1445 E Foothill Blvd UPLAND CA 91786, 1540 W. FOOTHILL BLVD UPLAND CA 91786, 2735 E Eastland Center Dr WEST COVINA CA 91791, 1550 Leucadia Blvd ENCINITAS CA 92024, 1266 E Valley Parkway ESCONDIDO CA 92025, 1330 East Grand Ave ESCONDIDO CA 92027, 1046 Mission Ave OCEANSIDE CA 92054, 2100 VISTA WAY OCEANSIDE CA 92054, 3405 Marron Rd OCEANSIDE CA 92056, 705 COLLEGE BLVD OCEANSIDE CA 92057, 2121 Imperial Ave SAN DIEGO CA 92102, 4840 Shawline St SAN DIEGO CA 92111, 3412 COLLEGE AVE. SAN DIEGO CA 92115, 6336 College Grove Way SAN DIEGO CA 92115, 3382 Murphy Canyon Rd SAN DIEGO CA 92123, 575 Saturn Blvd SAN DIEGO CA 92154, 710 DENNERY ROAD SAN DIEGO CA 92154, 13553-A San Bernardino Avenue FONTANA CA 92334, 4210 EAST HIGHLAND A HIGHLAND CA 92346, 16555 Von Karman Ave IRVINE CA 92606, 26502 TOWNE CENTER DRI FOOTHILL RANCH CA 92610, 71 Technology Dr IRVINE CA 92618, 8230 TALBERT AVENUE HUNTINGTON BEACH CA 92646, 6912 Edinger Ave HUNTINGTON BEACH CA 92647, 21134 Beach Blvd HUNTINGTON BEACH CA 92648, 951 Avenida Pico SAN CLEMENTE CA 92673, 27470 ALICIA PKWY LAGUNA NIGUEL CA 92677, 13331 BEACH BLVD WESTMINSTER CA 92683, 30491 Avenida De Las Flores RANCHO SANTA MARGARITA CA 92688, 3600 W McFadden Ave SANTA ANA CA 92704, 17099 Brookhurst St. FOUNTAIN VALLEY CA 92708, 121 N Beach Ave ANAHEIM CA 92801, 440 N Euclid St ANAHEIM CA 92801, 1120 S Anaheim Blvd ANAHEIM CA 92805, Lemon and Orange thorpe ANAHEIM CA 92817, 2595 EAST IMPERIAL HGWY BREA CA 92821, 629 S. Placentia Ave. FULLERTON CA 92831, 10912 Katella Ave GARDEN GROVE CA 92840, 11822 Gilbert St GARDEN GROVE CA 92841, 2300 NORTH TUSTIN ST ORANGE CA 92865, 479 N McKinley St CORONA CA 92879, 1290 E Ontario Ave CORONA CA 92881, 1375 E. Ontario Ave. CORONA CA 92881, 1560 West 6th St CORONA CA 92882
```

Comment: Happy to help, but I, and others, need to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thanks for the input

Comment: The length of the string for the 2nd argument to the MATCH function is limited to 255 characters.  I would suggest using `FIND` or `SEARCH` or `COUNTIF` with wild cards to determine if the shorter string is present in the longer string.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the input but I am not sure how to use those functions to get the value of a cell in a 3rd column.

Comment: I will post an answer with an example of how to use `FIND` to partial match an entry in one column of a table, and return the result in another column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld didn't know about the character limit - thats good to know! Do you have any reference resources you frequent? Tidbits like that are rarely in Microsoft's function help articles

Comment: @soulshined I just use MSDN and, if that doesn't work, I try an Internet search with Google. Many of the tidbits come from what others have posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using `FIND` to return a value in some other column related to the cell where there is a partial match.

If you execute `FIND` against the column of the table, it will return an array of `#VALUE` and a number depending on whether the item exists in the string.  You can then do a `LOOKUP` to find the last match by making the LOOKUP value a very large number, and the result vector the column you want to return.

You should be able to adapt the following to your data:

Given this `Table`: (note your long list of addresses is in B3)

[image]

and with the Address you are searching for in `B9`, you can use this formula to return the contents of the cell in column D:

```
=LOOKUP(1E+307,FIND(B9,Table1[Long List of Addresses]),Table1[Cell to Return])
```

[image]

Comment: New to learning advanced formulas here. This helped me a lot. Thank you. Im going to edit this questions title. I spent 20 min on other solutions that weren't specific to comma separated lists trying to make something work. This was the best solution with smallest formula footprint out of the previous 7 I've tried. Other questions are reference specific, not dynamic and related to something like "If cell contains text then" which isn't the goal in this scenario. We know it contains text, we need the OFFSET data.